# Programatically copy/clone from one sql db to another

Tags: java, sql-server

I have an SQL Server (Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition, version 10.50.1600.1) with two databases. I want to copy all contents from one to the other, and I want to do this programatically with Java.

Alternatively if there is a way (from Java code) to clone the database to create an identical copy, that would work too.

The solutions I've found so far seem to fall in to two categories:

- Get a resultset of all tables from source, for each table, copy it into destination
- Dump source to a file, import the file to destination

Is there probably a more simple solution to this?

Background:

We have tests that write to the database, so we need to create a fresh db for each test and to pass the tests it needs to be identical to the source.

Comment: You should not reinvent the wheel and use a database data migration system like [flyway](http://flywaydb.org/)

Comment: `backup` and `restore`?

Comment: This could help — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268057/how-to-create-table-based-on-jdbc-result-set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy table from one database to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624711/how-to-copy-table-from-one-database-to-another)