# Multiple Schema Access in Query

Tags: java, spring, mariadb

I have two tables in two different schemas. I have to join these two tables and fetch the record in java. maria DB does not support functions, so i can't use functions. Anyone is having any thought on this ?

Comment: Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: @codeforester Sorry, I can't share code as it is very confidential. I have 2 tables in two different schemas and i need to fetch record from both the tables in a single query.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377431/how-to-create-multiple-schema-connections-using-java

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.field1, t2.field1
  from schema1.tablename t,
       schema2.tablename t2
 where t.key = t2.key;
```